# How to get color from palette material ui

Tags: reactjs, colors, material-ui, themes

1)How to get color from the palette in `Typography`?
2)How to get color from the palette with the argument?

Code:-

1)

```
    <Box color = 'common.white' >
      <Typography color = '(i need common.white from palette like in Box, so how i can get it here )' >
        Some text  
      </Typography>
    </Box>
```

2. 

```
    <Box color = '(i need gray[arg] from palette what i need write here for use color with arg like gray[500])'>
      Some text
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to add predefined colors from `@material-ui`, import that color from `@material-ui/core/colors`, and then add that color with the argument using style prop.

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { green } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

export default function Color() {
  return (
    <Typography style={{color:green[600]}}>Green color with argument</Typography>
  );
}
```

For adding `common`, `primary`, `secondary` or any theme related colors, we need to use theme object of the `@material-ui`. So there are two ways to do that:-

1. **Using `useTheme` hook**

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import {useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Color() {
  const theme = useTheme()

  return (
    <Typography style={{color:theme.palette.primary.main}}>primary.main</Typography>
  );
}
```

2. **Using `makeStyles` which provides the `theme` object in the argument itself and no need to use `useStyles` separately.**

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Color() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography className={classes.secondaryColorStyle}>secondary Color using makestyles</Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.commonBlack}>common black and white using makestyles</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  secondaryColorStyle:{
    color:theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  commonBlack:{
    color:theme.palette.common.white,
    backgroundColor:theme.palette.common.black
  }
}));
```

working sandbox demo:
[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]